# android get default system font from native code

Tags: android, fonts, freetype2

We use custom freetype2 library to render fonts on android, but we want to use(to reduce build size) us fonts from the system. Is it possible, and how can we get system default font from native code?

Comment: If you want to use the system fonts, why are you using a font library at all?

Comment: because, this is a native app.

Comment: don't suppose you ever found a solution?